# Probablity of a bicycle having working lights infront given that the lights in the back work

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

P(bicycle having lights infront and back) = 0.31

P(bicycle only having lights infront) = 0.23

P(bicycle only having lights in the back) = 0.09.

The rest of the bicycles had no lights.

If you know that a bike has working frontlights, what is the probability that it also has working backlights?

I tried using conditional probability, the chance of backlights working given that it has working frontlights: $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cup B)}{P(A)}$ but I cant find a way to use this correctly to get the right answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}P(\text{Bike has working backlights }|\text{ Bike has working frontlights}) \\= \frac{P(\text{Bike has working backlights and frontlights})}{P(\text{Bike has working frontlights})}
=\frac{0.31}{0.23+0.31}
&=0.57\end{align}$$

This follows from
$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$$

Comment: Ah of course, I had actually calculated P(A) in the previous task. Thank you sir!